# Highslide - is it possible to disable automatic image resizing?

Tags: highslide

I just noticed that Highslide scripe resizes large images (make them smaller) to fit to the screen. Is it possible to disable this function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Highslide settings:

```
hs.allowSizeReduction = false;
```

Highslide API reference page: http://highslide.com/ref/hs.allowSizeReduction